# Unable to choose the correct file location in Android using Java

Tags: java, android, file, filesystems

I've realised that the problem in my reading and writing to a text file in Android is due to an incorrect reference to the file location. I do not understand where I am going wrong.

I have tried this method:

```
 File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/topics.json");
```

But the return statement is:

```
 W/System.err(8871): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /topics.json: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

---

I have also tried:

```
File file = getContext().getFileStreamPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/topics.json");
```

But receive error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(6886): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /storage/emulated/0/topics.json contains a path separator
```

Comment: have you added the permission to write to external storage`?

Comment: Yes i have added both read external and write external

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this :

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "topics.json");
```

Comment: I am still getting an error: W/System.err(10622): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /topics.json: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Ok i changed some other references but this made it work. Thanks!

Comment: That is impossible with above statement. Your error comes from other code. Maybe where you try to read that file. Use 'file.exists()` to check if it exists before you try to read or open an input stream.